# Comparing reactivity of benzaldehyde and 2-butanone for nucleophilic addition

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, reactivity

I was taught that, in general, aldehydes are more reactive than ketones because of two reasons: 1) less steric hindrance, and 2) alkyl groups on both sides of carbonyl group in ketones have a stronger +I effect and reduce the partial positive charge on the carbonyl carbon.

Here, even though the second compound is a ketone, it has small alkyl groups which would provide less hindrance than a bulky phenyl group in benzaldehyde. Also, there will be a resonance effect in benzaldehyde reducing the carbonyl carbon's positive charge more(?) than it would be reduced in butanone.

But my teacher said benzaldehyde would be more reactive, because "aldehydes > ketones in reactivity", and he also said that in butanone, electron donating and hindering groups are present on *both* sides of the carbonyl.

I would like a stronger argument (if there is one) for why the reactivity of benzaldehyde is more; comparing hindrance and electron donating behaviour like this doesn't seem concrete to me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "there will be a resonance effect in benzaldehyde reducing the carbonyl carbon's positive charge more(?) than it would be reduced in butanone." That's what you got wrong.

Comment: @Mithoron so 2 alkyl groups have stronger electron donating effect (+I) than one phenyl ring's +R?

Comment: Phenyl has **withdrawing** effect. If you drew relevant structure, you'd see it only donates mesomerically to oxygen, not carbon.